# android:Drawing of rectangle or oval depending on height

Tags: android, android-canvas, rect

I have a list of path objects which are rectangles stored in an arraylist.

This is my code as shown below:

```
    for (RectF rec : rects) {

        for( int i =0; i< rects.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(rects.get(i).height() + "g");
            while(rects.get(i).height() !=50 ){

                canvas.drawRect(rec, paint);
            }
                canvas.drawOval(rec, paint);

            }

    }
```

Basically, when the rectangle height is not equal to 50, I would like to draw an oval instead of a rectangle. Upon running the code above, both the oval and rectangle was drawn. What is wrong here? 
Please help thank you.

Comment: Why are you makeing a for and a while loop? do a simple if else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (RectF rec : rects) {
    System.out.println(rec.height() + "g");

    if(rec.height() != 50)
    {
        canvas.drawOval(rec, paint);
    }
    else
    {
        canvas.drawRect(rec, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Karum Varela currently, i want to drawText on top of every path object.I have tried but the text only appears on one path object. how do i go about coding it? I have updated the code above. Also, if i want to give a index to the rect name how do i go about it?

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should start a new question, and include the code you've tried. Cheers!